# Верно ли предложенное решение по оптимизации

Tags: android, оптимизация

Решил заморочиться с оптимизацией приложения.

Допустим такую ситуацию: имеется приложение с одним `Activity` в котором демонстрируется информация в 10-и `TextView`.

При запуске приложения, в `Activity`, загружается текст из настроек параметров (через SharedPreferences). И затем он помещается в `TextView`.

**Вопрос:** если в `Activity` вместо кода загрузки разместить код запуска `Service`, внутри которого будет тот самый код загрузки текста и размещения его в `TextView`. По завершению загрузки и размещения текста `Service` самостоятельно останавливается. Повлияет ли такой способ на оптимизацию и скорость самого приложения в лучшую сторону или наоборот только замедлит приложение?

Comment: Десять `TextView` -- тут нечего оптимизировать. Прогоните профайлером, може покажет какие узкие места. Оптимизация ради оптимизации -- зло.

Comment: соглашусь с  Eugene Krivenja, в вашем случае оптимизировать особо нечего. Все телодвижения только усложнят код.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, неверно. `Service`, как правило, находится в другом адресном пространстве и не связан с жизненным циклом `Activity`, связка `Service-Activity` - это отдельное упражнение - либо через `bind()` или через `Broadcast` и то и другое достаточно дорогие удовольствия.

Посадите загрузку в `AsyncTask` или на крайняк через rxJava и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Десять строк из SharedPreferences и для этого потоки плодить или RX тянуть? :)

Comment: @Barmaley извините, но как понимать Вашу фразу, что "Service, как правило, находится в другом адресном пространстве" ? ведь по умолчанию "Служба работает в основном потоке ведущего процесса — служба не создает своего потока и не выполняется в отдельном процессе (если вы не указали иное). "

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ,10 TextView - просто для примера. В моём случае к этом добавляется ещё GraphView и установка Backgraund'a :)